# Change CSS property of element based on parent element property

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am using `js-caurousal` to change background image which working fine. Further to it I also added caption for each slide which I am animating with Fade effect using `animation.css` and `wow.js`.

Issue I have is that animation only plays once and I want to play animation for caption text when ever slide is **active**. I tried to look for solution but I am not able to find much.

So I thought adding & removing `wow fadeIn` from element which has `slide-caption` class.

Below is the code for slideshow

```
<div class="js-carousel u-carousel-v5" data-autoplay="true" data-infinite="true" data-fade="true" data-speed="4000">
  <div class="js-slide g-bg-img-hero g-height-100vh--md g-min-height-300" aria-hidden="true" style="background-image: url(assets/img/1.jpg);">
    <h3 class="slide-caption wow fadeIn" data-animation="animated fadeIn" data-wow-delay="4s">Image One</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="js-slide g-bg-img-hero g-height-100vh--md g-min-height-300" aria-hidden="true" style="background-image: url(assets/img/2.jpg);">
    <h3 class="slide-caption wow fadeIn" data-animation="animated fadeIn" data-wow-delay="4s">Image Two</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I use following `$( ":hidden").attr( "aria-hidden", "true" )` to add and remove css from `slide-caption`

Comment: are you sure it's not `caurousel` with an E

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, i am using this template https://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v2.1/one-pages/wedding/index.html, It has the Carousal which say, but documentation doesn mentioned which carousel exactly

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Or even `carousel` (just one `u`).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I did not even noticed that first U... - so I already have a page with all the carousel misspells I've seen :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use it as **attribute selector** and do something like this :

```js
$('div[aria-hidden=false] .slide-caption').removeClass('wow fadeIn');
```

```css
.wow.fadeIn {
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-carousel u-carousel-v5"
             data-autoplay="true"
             data-infinite="true"
             data-fade="true"
             data-speed="4000">
<div class="js-slide g-bg-img-hero g-height-100vh--md g-min-height-300" aria-hidden="true" style="background-image: url(assets/img/1.jpg);">
        <h3 class="slide-caption wow fadeIn"  data-animation="animated fadeIn"  data-wow-delay="4s" >Image One</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="js-slide g-bg-img-hero g-height-100vh--md g-min-height-300" aria-hidden="true" style="background-image: url(assets/img/2.jpg);">
        <h3 class="slide-caption wow fadeIn"  data-animation="animated fadeIn"  data-wow-delay="4s" >Image Two</h3>
    </div>
    
    <div class="js-slide g-bg-img-hero g-height-100vh--md g-min-height-300" aria-hidden="false" style="background-image: url(assets/img/2.jpg);">
        <h3 class="slide-caption wow fadeIn"  data-animation="animated fadeIn"  data-wow-delay="4s" >Image Three</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not working for me i tried following two lines of code to add & remove the class to keep animation playing whenever slide loops again `$('div[aria-hidden=false] .slide-caption').removeClass('wow slideInUp');
  
  $('div[aria-hidden=true] .slide-caption').addClass('wow slideInUp animation');`

Comment: I used `wow fadeIn` also as i actuall use `wow slideInUp`. It breaks the animation for first slide itself 2,3 play but then when it loops back it doesnt play again. wow.js add & remove `animation` class automatically after animation plays once.

Comment: @Learning so i think the idea is to add !important property in CSS to override the animation and avoid it to loop again

Comment: I want animation to play when ever slide is active

Comment: @Learning so maybe you need to make your code automatic too .. did you have any event handler, when slide changes for example, where you can add the code ?

Comment: I initialize following code `new WOW().init();` for `wow.js` animation

Comment: @Learning if you check the github link and you scroll https://github.com/matthieua/WOW you will see that you can create a wow object with `callback` function .. maybe you can try it

Answer (score -1):

Do the styling like

```css
.parentProperty1 .childClr {
     color: red;
}

.parentProperty2 .childClr {
     color: blue;
}
```

```html
Your CSS Selector should be like
```